# How to skip top level @UseGuards decorator in a controller for a route?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

My controller looks like this:

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(Guard1, Guard2, Guard2)
export class NotesController {

  @Post()
  async create() {
    //........
  }

  @Get()
  async all() {
    //........
  }
}
```

I want the GET API to skip the guards. These guards are not using `app.useGlobalGuards()`. I tried the SetMetadata for skip decorator at the route level and check in the guards for it but the guards are executing before the SetMetadata decorator called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless if you're using a global guard or not, you should be able to create some sort of decorator like

```js
export const SkipGuard1 = SetMetadata('Guard1SkipMetadataToken', true)
export const SkipGuard2 = SetMetadata('Guard2SkipMetadataToken', true)
export const SkipGuard3 = SetMetadata('Guard3SkipMetadataToken', true)
```

Now, in each guard, you should inject the `Reflector` and in the `canActivate` method there should be a line along the lines of

```js
const shouldSkip = this.reflector.get('GuardNSkipMetadataToken', context.getHandler())
```

[as shown in the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata) (remember to replace the `N` with the guard number, or better yet, use string constants for the tokens)

If this metadata comes back as `true` then you short circuit the guard by `return true` before you get to the core logic of the guard. This way, you can still decorate the entire class as you have, but provide fine tuned controls for which guard(s) should activate for which route handler.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this [link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/964) to Exclude a route from Nestjs Auth Guard

Comment: Those guards are not Global Guards

Comment: Please do not write answers which depend on navigating to a link to get the answer. See [answer], the section titled "Provide context for links".